# About python selenium argument error,how could i handle the error with argument exception?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, arguments, syntax-error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XThxc.png)

Here is my code,and why it shows me the error with:InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'url' must be a string
(Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116):
`from selenium import webdriver

class LianJia:
def **init**(self):

```
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\HP\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')

def house_detail(self, item):
    
    self.driver.get(item['houseURL'])  
    # get the page info in house
    item['title'] = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('h1').text    # title
    item['price'] = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.offer__price').text    # price
    house_info = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.offer__info-item')
    item['room'] = house_info[0].text    # house
    item['faceTo'] = house_info[1].text   # faceto
    item['area'] = house_info[2].text     # area
   
    item['communityName'] = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.owners__name').text
    
    item['releaseDate'] = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "card-stats__item", " " ))]').text
    print(item)

def house_list(self, item):
   
    
    self.driver.get(item['partURL'])  
  
    self.driver.find_element_by_link_text('дорогие').click()
   
    house_ls = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/main/section[3]/div/section[1]')
   
    house_url_ls = [house.get_attribute("href") for house in house_ls]
  
    for url in house_url_ls:
        item['houseURL'] = url
        self.house_detail(item)

def run(self):
   
    self.driver.get('https://krisha.kz/prodazha/kvartiry/almaty/')    
    
    temp_ls = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "container", " " ))]')
  
    part_name_ls = [ele.text for ele in temp_ls]
  
    part_url_ls = [ele.get_attribute("href") for ele in temp_ls]
    item = {}   
    for i in range(len(temp_ls)):
        item['partName'] = part_name_ls[i]    
        item['partURL'] = part_url_ls[i]    
        self.house_list(dict(item))
```

if **name** == '**main**':
lj = LianJia()
lj.run()`

Comment: try this may be this will help you ``` item['houseURL'] = str(url)```

Comment: Thank you but it still shows the same error

Comment: You are getting any link in list ```part_url_ls```. {'partName': 'Избранное\nРегистрация\nЛичный кабинет', 'partURL': None}

Comment: ```item['partURL']``` is returning None. So you can not call ```self.driver.get(item['partURL'])```, has url error.